# Use Python Google Storage Client without credentials

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I am using the [Python Google Storage Client](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started), however I am using a bucket with public read/write access. (I know this is usually a terrible idea but I have a rare use case where it is fine).

When I try to retrieve some files, I get a `DefaultCredentialsError`.

```
BUCKET_NAME = 'my-public-bucket-name'
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

def list_blobs(prefix, delimiter=None):
    blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix, delimiter=delimiter)

    print('Blobs:')
    for blob in blobs:
        print(blob.name)
```

The specific error reads:

```
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

That page suggests using Oath or other tokens, but I shouldn't need these since my bucket is public? I can make an HTTP request to the bucket in chrome and receive data.

**How should I get around this issue? Can I provide default or null credentials?**

Answer (score 0):

The default for a storage client with no parameters is to use environment credentials (e.g. authenticate with the `gcloud` tools first). If you want to use a client with no credentials you have to use
the [create_anonymous_client](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.client.Client) method, which lets you access resources available to `allUsers`.

Be careful though which APIs you use, not all of them support anonymous credentials. E.g. instead of `client.get_bucket('my-bucket')` you have to use `client.bucket(bucket_name='my-bucket')`.

Also note that it seems any permissions error returns a generic `ValueError: Anonymous credentials cannot be refreshed.`. E.g. if you try to overwrite an existing file while only having read/write permissions.

So a full example of uploading a file to a publicly accessible bucket is

```py
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client.create_anonymous_client()
bucket = client.bucket(bucket_name='my-public-bucket')
blob = bucket.blob('my-file')
blob.upload_from_filename('my-local-file')
```

Answer (score -1):

From "[Cloud Storage Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication)":

> Most of the operations you perform in Cloud Storage must be authenticated. The only exceptions are operations on objects that allow anonymous access. Objects are anonymously accessible if the `allUsers` group has `READ` permission. The `allUsers` group includes anyone on the Internet.

Comment: Useful to know except that the error occurs within `storage_client = storage.Client()` so even if allUsers  is on read, there are no suggestions on how to update the doe in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer answers the question.